# col-md is overriding col-sm for lower resolution

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

*Col-md* is overriding *col-sm* in bootstrap-4

[image]

Comment: Looks correct, your screen width is at 980px, so its taking `col-md` rules.. try resizing to lesser than 576px and see if it takes the `col-sm` rule...

Comment: @Gosi checkout the updated screenshot

Comment: In the screenshot, I cant see the wrapping classes ".container-fluid/.container", ".row" etc. May be you can try with adding them in the DOM.

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman even with wrappers it does not work. sc updated!

Comment: Have you tried with reverse order `col-md-4 col-sm-12` instead of  `col-sm-12 col-md-4`?

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem but without success, so my best bet is that there are some other rules in place overriding the bootstrap's default. @Ishpreet the order of the classes in an html element is irrelevant, is the order of declaration in the .css file that maters.

Comment: @Dax, I know order of classes is irrelevant. But it is not working here, it is first time I see, that's why I just suggested, it was not solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical mobile-optimized site should contain something like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The `width` property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to a specific number of pixels like `width=600` or to the special value `device-width`, which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a scale of 100%. (There are corresponding `height` and `device-height` values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size or position based on the viewport height.)

The `initial-scale` property controls the zoom level when the page is first loaded. The `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, and `user-scalable` properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.